# in custom module creation how to see the base database table in drupal 7.15

Tags: module, drupal-7, entity, drupal-modules

I am creating a module in drupal 7.15 which is depended on the entity api .
my module name is employee
I have created a employee.info file, along with employee.install file.
But in the database i cant see my own created database schema in the employee.install file.
Here is my .info file and .install file respectively
edit:

```
name = Employee Management
description = A module that describes about the employee management 
core = 7.x
package = Employee management module
files[] = employee.module
```

edit:

```
<?php
/**
* @file
* Install for a employee entity - need to create the base table for our entity.
* This table can have as many colums as you need to keep track of entity-specific
* data that will not be added via attached fields.
* The minimum information for the entity to work is an id and an entity name.
*/

/**
* Implements hook_schema()
*/
function employee_schema() {
$schema = array();

$schema['employee'] = array(
'description' => 'The base table for employee entity.',
  'fields' => array(
   'employee_id' => array(
   'description' => 'Primary Key: Identifier for a employee entity.',
   'type' => 'serial',
   'unsigned' => TRUE,
   'not null' => TRUE,
   ),
   'first_name' => array(
   'description' => 'The First name of employee entity.',
   'type' => 'varchar',
   'length' => 255,
   'not null' => TRUE,
   'default' => '',
   ),
   'last_name' => array(
   'description' => 'The Last name of employee entity.',
   'type' => 'varchar',
   'length' => 255,
   'not null' => TRUE,
   'default' => '',
   ),
   'employee_add' => array(
   'description' => 'The address of employee entity.',
   'type' => 'varchar',
   'length' => 255,
   'not null' => TRUE,
   'default' => '',
   ),
   'employee_doj' => array(
   'description' => 'The address of employee entity.',
   'type' => 'date',
   'not null' => TRUE,
   'default' => '',
   ),
   ),
   'primary key' => array('employee_id'),
    );

return $schema;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the hook_schema() in .install file after you initially installed the module? Schemas only get installed when a module is installed. (not to be confused with enabled)

Try uninstalling the module completely, and re-installing it:

1) Disable the module
2) Uninstall the module (from the uninstall tab on the admin modules page)
3) Re-install the module

This should trigger hook_schema on install. Your implementation of the hook looks fine.

If there is a problem with the schema, you should see an error when you install the module. (after completely uninstalling it) If errors are not set to display on the screen, check reports -> db log.

Also note, you don't need to declare `files[] = employee.module` in your info file.